# filament led bulb inrush current

Tags: current, ac, relay, lamp

I'm tring to choose a relay for my circuit which has a [Filament LED bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_filament) as load.

The bulb is 230VAC / <s>60W</s> 6W.
The nominal current should be about 0.03A which is not an issue for a regular relay. The inrush current can go from 10 to 15 times that value, from what I understand. So it can go up to <s>3A</s>0.4A.

So I just need a relay that can handle a max switch current of <s>3A</s> 0.4A?

How can I control the inrush current before it goes to the relay? If I add another bulb to the circuit, I'll have to get another relay that can handle twice the current. And this is not a good idea in the long-term.

**UPDATE 23/03**

1. The bulb's power is 6W, not 60W as @Misunderstood pointed out.
2. I was able to probe the bulb in an osciloscope and the inrush current max was about 2A. The average value was about 1.5A. These values may not be much accurate because the probe used was for high current values and it has low sensitivity to low current values. The real inrush current is probably below these values but since it's not much and it doesn't require a special/expensive relay, I'm not too worried.
3. **Conclusion:** Since I'm not thinking of using more than 3 bulbs, I'll get a relay rated at >= 6A peak. I'll probably add a relay socket as suggested by @Harper and put everything inside a junction box. I'll add the full schematics (with the relay controller and the other switches) later, in a new post, so I can get some feedback.

**UPDATE-EDIT:**

4. I have used triacs, in the past, to control the brightness of a bulb but it wasn't a LED bulb. I was told triacs dont like LED bulbs and may not be suitable to be used as dimmers. What are my options here?

**Thanks** everyone for your help. Feel free to comment if my conclusion is wrong of if there's something I'm missing.

EDIT: Added schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK2Wvd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How did this get flagged for a product recommendation? It is asking about inrush current.

Comment: A NTC thermistor is commonly used for this.  As it heats the resistance goes away.

Comment: "LEDs are not subject to this limitation. LED current is controlled by a resistor, so you can use the relay's full current rating." Is this correct ? Are LED lamps not subject to inrush corrents ?

Comment: When you say lamp you mean a store bought lamp that uses LEDs rather than light bulbs correct?  so this would not have anything to do with LEDs if that is correct.  And in this case the LED are not likely controlled by a resistor.  Most commercial lighting products use multiple medium powered LEDs and a current regulator.

Comment: @Misunderstood I mean LED bulbs. [edison led filament-like bulbs](http://bit.ly/11luG3j) (edited)

Comment: For most LED lamp power supplies, the inrush current is caused by the input stage filter capacitor(s) charging.  This is usually not much problem for small LED lamps but can be significant for larger LED bulbs (100W or more).  If the power supply manufacturer did NOT provide for inrush current limiting, you can easily add an appropriate NTC thermistor in series with the power input.  Do note that these require sufficient cool-down time before reapplying power should power be interrupted.

Comment: @DwayneReid Sorry, im not following. What I have are led-filament bulbs like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_filament). Does that apply to this specific bulbs ? The only way of checking if the manufacturer did a good job is by measuring the current with an oscilloscope, right ?

Comment: @DwayneReid, after some research, it seems most of these bulbs come with a inrush current limiting resistor. I guess I really should try to use an oscilloscope on this to check the values.

Comment: @nip 60 watts of LED is a *staggering* amount of light, more like a 500W halogen.  that would never exist in that style. More likely you have a "60W equivalent" that's about 8 watts.  *Conservatively* assuming a terrible 34% Power Factor, that's 24VA or 0.10 amps, not considering inrush current.

Comment: @Harper Yes, its 60W equivalent. Its 6W LED.

Comment: @Harper Now that you are talking about that, I got the current using 60W. If I do the math with 6W, the current will be about  0.026A. And if I consider a worst-case scenario of a 15x inrush current, thats only 0.39A.

Comment: Forget about the last comment, those values are not correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Look at the *listed* amp rating of your bulb

You need to look at your bulb's documentation/data sheet for its listed draw in *amps*.  If it provides a **VA** rating, you can compute amps from VA/volts.  If it provides **actual watts** and **power factor**, you can compute Watts/Volts/PF.  LED bulbs are often marketed as "Same brightness as a 60 watt incandescent bulb", that is a meaningless number.

### Look at the rating of your relay

Inrush current is a big current surge on initial startup, but no particular reactivity when interrupted.  (contrast with an inductive load which has a huge kick when interrupted, and the kick can leap across contacts).  The inrush current on your consumer LED-based lamp product is lesser than that on an incandescent bulb.  Look at the rating on the relay.  Relays are listed at different power ratings for

- resistive (usually the highest number)
- motor (huge inductive kick)
- ballast (meaning *magnetic* ballasts, also a big inductive kick)
- ***Tungsten* (meaning incandescent bulb, meaning inrush current)**

If it lists a *tungsten* amp rating, then you can use that figure straight-up; they already compensated for inrush current and UL/CSA/TUV etc. listed it as such.  You don't need to.

### Comply with Code - use the right relays

Since you are switching mains voltage, you must also comply with your local electrical codes.  They will require that you use not random components, but assemblies listed for mains use.  Contrast:

[image]
[image]

The first is a bare component, you'd need to solder wires to it and then what?  Wrap it in electrical tape and leave it to flop around in a junction box?  Unacceptable with mains.

The second one is designed to mount on a standard junction box fitting. Note how this puts the *mains* wiring *inside* the junction box, and the low-voltage wiring outside. This satisfies separation requirements of high voltage and low voltage wiring.  Once outside the high-voltage "envelope" you are subject to the much more liberal low-voltage wiring rules, same as telephone; or doorbell or thermostat in countries where that is low-voltage.

### Relay the relays

There are many relays like the second one.  Some may be 5V coil. But other voltages will be much more readily available, e.g. 24V is popular in North America. This may not be a problem: some have a **built-in transformer** that matches their coil.  These devices supply you 2 wires - *if you short them, the relay picks up.  Simple as that.*  You can do  that with the 5V relay of your choice.

Even better, 24V travels well.  That means you can switch the mains voltage *in the location that makes sense*, i.e. down at the service panel/mains supply or somewhere it's easy to access an electrical box to mount it... keep the 5V near your PC... and let the intermediate coil voltage do the traveling.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. Honestly, I havent thought of how I'd assemble the circuit yet. I was thinking of testing it on a breadboard and then print a pcb. Its the first time I see those types of relays, and I've searched in 2/3 electronics stores in my city. But the thing is, you don't really answer my question. I know there are relays capable of dealing with 2/3 bulbs but my issue is the long-term scability. If I'm dealing with only 1 bulb, I can have a 4A relay. If by some reason I decide to use 3 , I need to get a 12A relay. I'd rather have a solution that wasn't dependent on the relay.

Comment: Having this is mind, what do you think about the solution suggested by @Misunderstood of using a NTC thermistor ?

Comment: See edits. If the relay has a *tungsten* rating, that accounts for inrush current and you don't need to factor for it. That's a solid gold number some listing agency (UL/CSA/TUV) stands behind.  So a 10A *tungsten* relay can drive dozens of 0.20A lamps.  Don't need that thermistor, the system is built to handle inrush current.  You won't find these parts in *any* electronics stores because mains electrical is a totally different discipline with totally different supply chain. Check it out, more arrows in your quiver!

Comment: I'll have to look more into that. So far I've seen dozens of relay datasheets and I've never seen a Tungsten rating.

Comment: The bulbs dont have any documentation, they are a cheap "replica". That's why I wanted to check with the osciloscope, to make sure it wasn't making weird things.

Comment: The relay should go in the lamp where electrical codes do not come into play.  With a 30mA load, Contactor Tungsten is not going to come into play either.

Comment: @Misunderstood Electrical codes apply anywhere there's mains voltage.   "Inside the lamp" indeed does allow listed electronic parts to be used.  The rules are much relaxed for low-voltage and that's a good reason to do entire projects in low voltage (except for a listed wall-wart).   OP can't count on the load being 30ma unless all the bulbs are soldered-in, which *is* an option to settle the code issue.  Otherwise he must build for the wife, tenant or next owner unscrewing those bulbs and sticking 100W incandescents in there.  OP is being prudent, which is good.

Answer (score 2):

These bulbs are made to be switched on with regular household switches.

You need not do anything other than adding the relay. Current will be about 30mA.  Nearly any relay will do the job.

All the other "60W" filament LED bulbs are in the same class 7-10 Watts.

There is a table on this site: [The Next Generation of LED Filament Bulbs](http://www.ledinside.com/knowledge/2015/2/the_next_generation_of_led_filament_bulbs)

**5 Watt,  375 Lumens, Filament LED Bulb**

[image]

---

This is a 60W Equivalent Soft White by Westinghouse, it draws 7.5 Watts.

[image]

---

**6.5 Watt, EcoSmart 60W Equivalent Soft White A19 Dimmable Filament LED Light Bulb**

[image: EcoSmart 60W Equivalent Soft White A19 Dimmable Filament LED Light Bulb]

---

### UPDATE

You may find something like this in the base of an LED light bulb.

[image]

---

What I found at the patent office was this image. The base (10) "contains a control board".  This base is smaller than the above circuit board.

[image]

> The LED light bulb 8 includes, in its base 10 hermetically sealing the
>   opening of a glass cover 12, a control board (not shown) that converts
>   commercial electric power into electric power for driving the LEDs.

---

### THE BASE

[image]

> As shown in figures, the LED light bulb provided by the present
>   invention at least includes: a bulb base 10, an insulation part 20, a
>   power module 30, a support post 40, a light source module 50 and a
>   lampshade 60.
>
> The bulb base 10 is e.g. but not limited to an E26/E27/B22 connector.
>   If being applied in a small LED light bulb, an E12 connector used in a
>   small nightlight can be adopted. If being applied in a large
>   illumination lamp, an E40 connector can be adopted. According to one
>   embodiment of the present invention, an E27 connector is adopted for
>   illustration and shall not be a limitation to the scope of the present
>   invention.
>
> The insulation part 20 is disposed on the bulb base 10, formed as e.g.
>   but not limit to a hollow barrel-shaped structure, and formed with an
>   accommodation space 21, the bottom thereof is formed with a thread 22
>   for being screw-fitted in the bulb base 10, two sides thereof are
>   respectively formed with a fasten post 23, the top end of the fasten
>   post 23 is formed with a fasten hole 24. Wherein, the insulation part
>   20 is made of a plastic material. In addition, a slide groove 25 is
>   respectively formed between the two fasten posts 23 of the insulation
>   part 20. Moreover, the insulation part 20 can be served to insulate
>   the power module 30 thereby complying with relevant safety
>   regulations.

---

### The Filament

[image]

> The substrate 10 is set to be of an elongated bar-shaped construction
>   to constitute a main body of the LED filament. In present embodiment,
>   the length of the substrate ranges from 5.00 mm to 200.00 mm, the
>   width thereof ranges from 0.50 to 10.00 mm, and height thereof ranges
>   from 0.10 mm to 5.00 mm.  the light emitting unit 20 is fastened onto
>   at least one side surface of the substrate 10, and includes plural
>   regularly distributed blue light chips 21 and red light chips 22. The
>   blue light chips 21 and red light chips 22 are sequentially connected
>   to one another in series by a metal conductive cable 40. Two ends of
>   the substrates 10 are provided with electrode pins 50 connected
>   respectively to the two ends of the metal conductive cable 40.

---

### INRUSH???

The 6 filaments are connected in series as are the 25 LEDs in each filament.
this is about 150 LEDs, red and blue mixed, so a forward voltage on average of 2.5v so about 375 volts total forward current. At 5 Watts that about 13 mA.

So there must be a rectifier and tiny boost regulator in the base.

Not much to create massive inrush.

The 1.5 to 2 Amp inrush your are seeing sounds a bit high for these circumstances.

How was the current measured.  The voltage across a shunt resistor?

### VIDEO

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NffhdAz9pc4) was enlightening.  The rectifier and linear current regulator is what I'd expect. The light bulb in the video, the filaments were not connected in series like the patent.  The current regulator is the equivalent of a dynamic resistor that adjusted its resistance to the voltage applied.

For a linear regulator to work the LED voltage must be less than the power supplied.

This means no capacitor and no inductor which equals no inrush.

The one bulb with the capacitor in the beginning of the video would create negligible inrush.

---

Now this is a 553 Watt LED grow light. It has 144 3 Watt and 48 2 Watt LEDs.   These put out the equivalent light of a 1000 Watt HPS lamp.

An indoor farm may have dozens of these. When you flip the switch on them I'll expect some inrush.  Not yours.

[image]

---

Now compare the little LED PCB above to this power supply.  This power supply has some serious inductors and capacitors.

It's the capacitors (fast charging batteries)  and inductors (building magnetic field on startup) that create inrush.

[image]

Comment: But other types of bulbs (incandescent or halogen, e.g) are also made for that purpose and they also have inrush currents. At least, thats the idea I got by researching about it. Either way, I'm going to try and take the bulb to uni and measure it on an osciloscope.

Comment: Your current is only about 30mA, not much of an inrush.  Where I see the inrush thermistor used is in high wattage power supplies and amplifiers.  I'm not sure what you are reading that has you so concerned. You have no reason to be concerned.

Comment: The inrush corrent is about 10-15 times the nominal current. If the bulb is 30mA, the inrush current can be 3A-4.5A. Using 3 bulbs, it goes up to 9A-13.5A. This was my concern. By testing the bulbs I have here, I was able to measure the inrush current, which is about 2A (max). In case I have 3 bulbs, I only need a 6A peek relay. If I didnt test, and guessed the value, I'd probably get a 15A peek relay. A NTC thermistor is used in similar scenarios but I'd have to make ajustments because they are not designed for fast-switching.

Comment: @nip No, the inrush cannot be that large.  There is nothing there to generate it.  There has to be a low impedance that creates the inrush. An LED light bulb does not have that kind of capacity to absorb 3-4.5 amps like a motor or amplifier.  Electrons will not go where there is no emf to compel the electron to go there. You do not need an NTC because there is not enough current to generate heat.  I do not know why fast switching and adjustments were mentioned.  It's just a relay, a mechanical switch, nothing going on here.

Comment: Okay I searched for inrush light bulbs and something did come up on LED lamps.  You have a 7 Watt bulb.  These inrush discussions are relating to turning on thousands of watts of LED fixtures.  An LED fixture can require 500 Watts and there may be many of them that need to be turned on. The inrush is caused by the power supplies providing all that wattage.  Your 7 watt bulb has no huge capacitors or inductors that would suck up electrons. Especially yours, there is no place to put a power supply like what is used in other LED light bulbs.  The base is too small.

Comment: From what I understand, the inrush current happens for a short period of time when the impedance is low and the bulb is "starting". This is a really short period of time. I didn't open the bulb but some have a inrush current limiting resistor, smoothing capacitors, regulators, etc. There are a lot of diferent circuits inside these. But I can assure you that me and 2 techs saw the inrush currents on the osciloscope. I turned the bulb on/off multiple times and most of the times this was around 1.5A. (1 of 2)

Comment: The maximum it reached was 2A. But as I said in the update, the probe was not ideal for this, and I was told the real value is probably a bit lower than what I measured. (2 of 2)

Comment: The current was measured using a current probe like [this](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1YT6wJpXXXXbkXVXXq6xXFXXX1/100KHz-AC-DC-font-b-Current-b-font-font-b-Probe-b-font-for-font-b.jpg). There are bulbs like this that have 45 LED's per filament. And some have 2 sets (in series) of 3 filaments in parallel.

Comment: I had to do this in like 10mins because the techs were about to leave the lab and I completly forgot to write down the nominal current. Im pretty sure it was above 13mA but I'll check that later.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that my bulbs in particular are chinese low-cost bulbs. The internal circuit is probably not like the one you posted. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NffhdAz9pc4) a teardown of a filament led bulb

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. What you are saying makes sense but goes against the measurements I made today. I know the conditions weren't ideal but the difference in values is too much for me to neglect. I seriously don't know what Im supposed to do now. I have some 1A relays with me and I can easily test them. But I'm worried about testing this in 230 VAC in my house. And even more doing it in a uni's lab. What's the worst case scenario, if the inrush is 2A in a 1A relay ? Dead relay only ? Fuses go off in the main board ?

Comment: Worst case is the contacts on the relay get arced.  There will be no safety issue other than you touching the 230 line.  A 1 amp relay should be way more than enough.

Comment: In that case, what damage can I expect on the main board ? A fuse blowing up ? Or just the circuit breaker shutting down ?

Comment: None. Unless you create a short in your wiring.  The LED bulb will not be the cause of any destruction or safety issues.

Comment: Incandescents have inrush due to their unique characteristics.  LEDs may or may not have inrush depending on how their power supplies are designed. I've seen LEDs such as those 50W direct-wire types that have no caps, and only light when the AC waveform is above their operating voltage, i.e. Shimmer.   You never know with the cheap Chinese stuff.  **If these lamps are screw-in, then *you never know* what OP or the next owner might install.** This is why you need to do things to Code and use assemblies listed for mains use.

Comment: @Harper  I get you, it's me.  I have an issue with code enforcement.   I had $300,000 house with over $800,000 in code enforcement fines. I walked away.  I have issues with rules and authority too.  My rule is to know the rules so you know how to break them properly.  Tungsten low room temperature resistance is not that unique but it is different from inductive and capacitive loads.  The what else might get screwed in, you got me there.  Did not see that one coming.   I do think this issue is getting hyped and is a misinterpretation of some online write ups regarding LED inrush.

Comment: I agree OP is over-worrying inrush.  I certainly can see your dislike of Code!  You have to be careful though because this foten occurs:  1. code seems obstructive 2. reverse-engineer the reason for the code.  3. make it so the reason is no longer applicable (this part is flawless) 4. SURPRISE. 5. discover that the reasoning in (2) was contaminated by confirmation bias, code had unforeseen reasons for existing which interlocked with other issues.  Happens a lot.

Comment: I understand why you say im over-worrying, you both have more knowledge about electronics than me, but consider this: I have "limited" experience with 230VAC; I don't want to mess-up the main board or make a fire because of a home-automation diy project. Now, what is really making me confuse is the different answers/information I get from different people/the internet. (1/2)

Comment: Some articles talk about LED lamps being subject to inrush currents (as the other types are), and most of them agree on the 10x-15x "factor". (reason1: because they have low impedance when turning-on) @Misunderstood says they are neglectable. You (@Harper) basically say "it's possible". I know this comes down to 1A relay vs 2A relay (for a single bulb) but I'd like to get a concrete answer, because over-dimensioning the components is not really an answer. (2/2)

Comment: I've read the entire thread once again, and this is what I got:

1. 6W bulb nominal current is about 20mA.
2. Even if there is an inrush current of 15x, its only 300mA.
3. The measurements I made today had a lot of 1A/1.XA readings, it even reached 2A once. |

From here, I can only think of 2 options: 

1. Re-do the measurements and see what I get. (the probe will be the same, rated for high current values, not ideal)
2. Go with the theoretical calculations and try a 1A relay.

Comment: PS: If the probe/environment(eg: isolation)/whatever were the reason for the wrong readings, I won't be able to fix that, since we only have that single probe on my department.

Comment: @nip that's the trouble, it's so easy to get lost in the overthinking of it, spin your wheels a *lot* and still end up with something that's bad, unsafe or illegal. Your *time* is worth money too.  There's nothing wrong with a little overkill, what matters is solve it *surely*, put the problem in your rearview mirror so you can work on cooler stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In rush can handles with a circuit to track the voltage crossing and enabling an AND logic switch at about the zero crossing.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. The zero-cross solution does not solve the problem of the inrush on the first cycle or two when the internal LED power supply capacitors are discharged and have to be charged from empty. There's an edit link below your answer if you wish to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the bulb, it seems that the electronic circuitry is simply a rectifier full-wave feeding a capacitor (filtering) then a resistor and Leds.
Formely and statisticaly, the inrush current peak may be very high if turn-on occurs on the maximum voltage (need of fuse).
In fact, it can be a short-circuit, thus current not limited. A NTC may be needed inside before the capacitor but is costly.
That is the reason why electronical switches can not be used for dimming with some kind of bulbs.